# Using GNU Debugger, how can I step through __asm__ statements?

Tags: gdb, debugging

```
  __asm__("\n\
    movl $1, %eax\n\
  ");
```

How can I step through `__asm__` so I can print the registers to see what they are storing? Right now, I put a break on the `__asm__` line and then I tried pressing `stepi` or `si` and it's not stepping into the `movl` line. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `si` *is* stepping over the `movl` instruction (you can verify this by typing `display/i $pc` and observing how the output changes.

What isn't happening (and what likely confused you) is update to the source. That's because your code inside **asm**() does not have any line-number annotations, so GDB can't tell which line(s) it should be displaying.

Normally, the compiler puts such annotations into the assembly. But here you've bypassed the compiler. If you want line numbers to be correct, you'll have to add these annotations yourself (which usually isn't worth the trouble).

Comment: What is `$pc`? Program counter?

Comment: yes, $pc is the program counter, the value of $rip on x86_64.
entering `layout regs` helps in stepping visually, a --tui view.